# Scaling by origin certain parts of a mesh

Tags: mesh

I'm trying to shrink the distance between the ends of three identical meshes toward the median of their origins, keeping their actual edge loops the same size/dimensions.

The intent isn't to merge the meshes, just want to close the gap.

[image: I want to move the edges towards each other while maintaining their shape.]

Is this something I can do in one continuous action or will I need to edit all three separately?